# ¿Como hacer una pregunta previamente al querer modificar un campo de una tabla en MS Access?

Tags: ms-access, macros

Tengo un campo nombrado `Informe_Tec1` que pertenece a una tabla `ArticulosCliente`, la situación radica en que se necesita ya sea una macro o una regla validación para el campo mencionado, donde se genere un `Msgbox` que pregunte: si ¿se desea modificar la información previamente digitada? en el formulario que contiene el campo.

Nota: esto a modo de ejemplo: cuando un técnico, ya sea por equivocación o el/ella necesite corregir un diagnostico antes realizado, el formulario primero pregunte si ¿desea modificar la información antes digitada en ese campo?. Si oprime **SI** (permita ingresar nueva información en `Informe_Tec1`), de lo contrario si se oprime **NO** (no se permita agregar/borrar algún tipo de carácter/letra o ninguna tecla), para evitar alteración de datos en `Informe_Tec1`.

Comment: Lectura sugerida: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y cual es el problema???